# Angular + internet explorer 9 The provided animation property "transform" is not a supported CSS property for animations

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9

Tengo un proyecto de `Angular 7.14` y quiero hacerlo compatible con la versión 11, 10 y 9 de Internet Explorer, pero en la versión 9 no puedo abrir diálogos de Angular Material. Recibo estos errores en la consola:

> ERROR Error: The animation trigger "dialogContainer" has failed to
>   build due to the following errors: The provided animation property
>   "transform" is not a supported CSS property for animations.

He leído que Internet Explorer 9 no admite animaciones, así que eliminé y desinstalé animation-js pollyfills, pero algunas animaciones siguen estando disponibles.

Comment: Hola, estás en StackOverflow en Español.

Comment: no me había fijado!! gracias! por cierto, sabes como se solucionaría esto?

Answer (score 0):

Al final me decanté por crear mis propios dialogos ya que ví que no se puede desactivar la animación del dialog en angular (lo probe con triggers como @.disabled).
Aquí os pongo un tutorial que me sirvio para implementarlos.
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/16/angular-7-custom-modal-window-dialog-box